# Getting an error when trying to connect to MongoDB on Mlab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I've created a free DB on MLab and I've set up the connection in node, but when i try to insert I get an error:

> Error:not authorized on capina to execute command { insert:
>   \"products\", documents: [ { _id:
>   ObjectId('5b255d56a7be644ca873631e'), name: \"טארלט מלוח אישי\",
>   priceNoVAT: 0.97, priceVAT: 1.05, quantityPerUnit: 150, unit:
>   \"ארגז\", totalPrice: 130, __v: 0 } ], ordered: true }"

Here is the connections code:

```
//works fine, no error here
mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb://" +
      process.env.MONGO_USERNAME +
      process.env.MONGO_PWD +
      "@ds161620.mlab.com:61620/" + process.env.DB_NAME
  )
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Here is the model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  priceNoVAT: Number,
  priceVAT: Number,
  quantityPerUnit: Number,
  unit: String,
  totalPrice: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

and here is the test route I'm trying to call and get the error:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const product = new Product({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: "טארלט מלוח אישי",
    priceNoVAT: 0.97,
    priceVAT: 1.05,
    quantityPerUnit: 150,
    unit: "ארגז",
    totalPrice: 130
  });

  product
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      res.json({ message: "Product Saved" });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.json({ message: "Error:" + err.message });
    });
});
```

The username/password are defined properly and when i log it, i see i get the correct values, so I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it, it's a stupid mistake but yet, it can happen to someone else, so I'm posting the answer here:

I forgot to add ":" between the username and password, so:

```
"mongodb://" +
      process.env.MONGO_USERNAME +
      process.env.MONGO_PWD +
      "@ds161620.mlab.com:61620/" + process.env.DB_NAME
```

should actually be:

```
"mongodb://" +
      process.env.MONGO_USERNAME +
      ":" +
      process.env.MONGO_PWD +
      "@ds161620.mlab.com:61620/" + process.env.DB_NAME
```